# Notice: Array to string conversion convert array to string

Tags: php, arrays, session, notice

I want to convert all session's keys and values to the string. When I run this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array['language'] = 'Asdfgh';
$array['currency'] = 'Asdfgh';
$array['cart'][] = 'Asdfgh';
$array['cart'][] = 'Asdfgh';
$array['facebookpagelikeshowed'] = 'Asdfgh';
$array['vid_yMHe4j2Ouko']['uid'] = '170785079';
$array['vid_yMHe4j2Ouko']['vid'] = '170785079';

    $text = '';
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    { 
        $text .= ''.$key.'='.$value.';';
    }
    echo $text;
?>
```

I got this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/index.php on line 16
```

Why? How can I resolve it?

Comment: Which line is line 70 in your code?

Comment: must be `$sessionvalue .= ''.$key.'='.$value.';';`

Comment: What are you try to doing inside foreach?
Anyway, just use `$value['name_of_session']` instead of  `''.$key.'='.$value.'` and you should pass it fine.

Comment: @Aliyev Rauf: depends on what you're trying to achieve. You seem to want to convert the data to pass it to some other component. What format does your other component expect for arrays ?

Comment: Line 70: $sessionvalue .= ''.$key.'='.$value.';';

Comment: what are the values inside your Array? Specifically the ```['2354::']```? Looks like there is a problem trying to parse this

Comment: I added my session array. Please check again

Comment: You'll need to add in a check to see if it is an array, and if it is an array you'll have to parse it again.
If you're just trying to output everything you have onto the screen, you could possibly use ```var_dump($ARRAYNAME)``` - what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: I guess a good question is what are you hoping the overall output of this will be?

Comment: Use `var_export` maybe?

Comment: I updated this question. Please check

Comment: @AliyevRauf If you just want to convert arrays to strings to solve the immediate problem, try serialize. Change line 70 to $sessionvalue .= $key.'='.serialize($value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when foreach reach the $key `vid_yMHe4j2Ouko` $value is of type `array` so you can't use the concat operator (`. $value`)